# How do can I wire up an event to trigger after methods of my choosing finish execution in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, events, jquery-events

Hard to summarize in one question, but here are the details:

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project (many of them actually).

My standard practice is for each view to have an `Init()` method that is fired when the document is ready. This is where I put all my UI code, like rendering buttons and accordions, etc.

I am using the trick to hide un-formatted html elements by setting the `html` tag to `display: none` and after `Init()` is complete, I can unhide everything.

This works pretty well, but I initially had the showing of content in my layout page, but that would execute before the Init code of a view finished running. It gets even more complex if I use partial views with their own Javascript.

What I would like is to attach a callback in one place that fires after the all of my possible `Init()` calls are finished.

I tried using custom events, but then I would have to trigger them at the end of every Init method, and that's not very efficient.

Requested Code:

**Layout Page**

```
<script>
     $("html").addClass('init') // init has display: none
     $(function() {
          InitLayout() // Basic stuff for every page like menu, buttons, etc

          $("html").removeClass('init'); // show all content
     });
</script>
```

**View Page**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
         ViewInit() // Init all custom ui elements on page: tabs, accordions, etc
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that the `removeClass` will occur before each page's `Init` fires. I am trying to find a way to avoid having the `removeClass` call at the bottom of every `Init` method. Is there some way to attach a callback programmatically to avoid repeating code. My main goal here is to implement hiding of unstyled content until everything is complete globally so I don't have to worry about it in each view.

Comment: post at least some pseudo code that gives some idea of sequence of events... otherwise question is a bit abstract

Comment: I notice you tagged this with jQuery. Are you using `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: @charlietfl I added some code to help demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to register the occurence of the init procedure into a global variable (array). This should be done outside of the document.ready() or JQuery equivalent. So within the `<script>` tags.

When your Init functions, inside the document.ready() event handler or it's JQuery equivalent , are finished, unregister the occurence.

While unregistering, check if there are any occurences left, if not, modify your html style.

The gap between script parsing and the DOM actual finishes loading could be working for you in this case.

Comment: So now I would have to add code to every method call checking if it's the last one in the array? Maybe something like this could be done with deferreds and $.when()...

Comment: Not really, if you have a global function to unsubscribe the init, you could do the checking there, just call that function in the init's